# Google analytics for mobile combined with website

Tags: google-analytics

I have 2 separate Google analytics properties - one for my mobile site (m.example.com) and one for my main site (example.com).

I switched over to universal.js and thought that the data for each would be combined. It has not been.

Instead of a new property, should I just create a new view in Google analytics for that sub domain and change my code on m.example.com to use the UA-XXXXXXX-Y that is the same as example.com?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As Google has no migration tools available for bringing properties together, you have two options available to you.

If you see any value in the historical data of m.example.com and the separation of the two versions of the site, then you can create a new rollup property which can track both example.com and m.example.com. You still get the advantages of having each separate and how people interact with each version of your site, but you can also see how people go between the two sites by leveraging your rollup property.

The other alternative, as you mentioned, would be to use the tracking code for just one property and use it on both sites. While you lose some ability to see how people interact with your site on a desktop vs a mobile device, you gain some ease and speed of implementation and getting reports.